# View Controller won't dismiss and present new view controller immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller once the QRCode reader has been dismissed, however when doing this the QRCode reader view controller is presented again. The code snippet below shows the method and how I'm dismissing the view and how I'm trying to present the next view controller. Any idea on why the QR reader view controller keeps presenting its self when I try to present a different controller.

```
func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(ClockInOrOutViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can't do this.You should present new controller only when previous one is fully dismissed.

Comment: @Vikky How do you propose I do this?

Comment: I thought Konrad Piękoś's answer would be working.But it didn't as you comment suggests.So now you have to use protocols and delegates to solve your problem.Take a look at https://medium.com/swift2go/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers-via-delegate-protocols-4ecde4b167de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `present` inside the **completion** handler of the `dismiss`.

```
func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {

    weak var presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        presentingViewController?.present(ClockInOrOutViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

If this does not work, it means your presenting view controller has also been removed somehow. (dismissed/popped?)

Comment: Just tested your solution, it gives me the same problem as what I started with and throws this error in the debugger '<ClockIn.QRCodeViewController: 0x102c00db0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: I don't think this will work.You can't present from a disimssing ViewController

Comment: @Vikky you are right, you need an instance of the view controller that presents the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't present view controller while other view controller is dismissing and also present on dismissing view controller.
You can do something like this:

```
func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
   let presenting = self.presentingViewController
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
      presenting?.present(ClockInOrOutViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
   }) 
}
```

Comment: Your solution still returns me and I still have the same error. '<ClockIn.QRCodeViewController: 0x102c00db0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'

Comment: It depends how you presented previous view controller You can also try this: 
`func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
      let presenting = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
      presenting?.present(ClockInOrOutViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
   }) 
}`